# flutter doctor: cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

A few hours ago I installed Flutter using SNAP, then I ran the "flutter doctor" and it returned the following error...

[ cannot change profile for next exec call: No such file or directory ]

[flutter doctor: cannot change profile for the next exec call: No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Skdm.png)

I believe I have to get to the installation directory, but I don't know how to do it.
I ask for help.
Since now, thank you very much for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with other package, re-installing the package worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get reinstall package_name
```